# Find all solutions to $f(x+f(x))=2x$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Question: Find all solutions to $f(x+f(x))=2x$

Attempt: So $f(x)=x$ is pretty trivial, but by some trial and error I've also found $f(x)=-2x$. Are these the only solutions? If so, how could I go about proving that?

Comment: Inserting $x=0$ gives $f(f(0))=0$. Using this, inserting $x=f(0)$, we get $f(0)=0$.  So there is that. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Two observations: If $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, then $f(x+f(x))= f(2x) = 2x$, so $2x$ is a fixed point as well.

Suppose $f(x) = kx$ for some real $k$. Then $f(x+f(x)) = k(k+1)x = 2x$ hence $k(k+1) = 2$, so $k=1,-2$. So among the lines in the plane, $x$ and $-2x$ are the only ones since $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Sisyphus I found that. But I am curious if there are any other solutions.

Comment: Using the functional equation, there is the fact that $\frac{1}{2}f(x+f(x))=x$ meaning that $(\frac{1}{2}f(x))^{-1}=x+f(x)$ assuming $f$ is bijective

Comment: What should be the domain? All of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes, real functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = -2x$ are the only *continuous* solutions. We begin by explicitly mentioning this assumption.

> **Assumption.** $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function that solves the functional equation
>
> $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ : \quad f(x+f(x)) = 2x. $$

The idea is to consider the function $m(x) = f(x)/x$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. To investigate the property of this function, we show the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $f$ be as in the assumption. Then
>
> 1. $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.
> 2. $f(x) = -x$ if and only if $x = 0$.

*Proof.* If $f(x) = 0$, then $0 = f(x) = f(x+f(x)) = 2x$ and hence $x = 0$. For the other direction, notice that $f(f(0)) = 0$. So by the previous step, we find that $f(0) = 0$.

Now assume that $f(x) = -x$. Then $2x = f(x+f(x)) = f(0) = 0$ and hence $x = 0$. The other direction is clear from the previous step. ////

From this lemma, we know that $m(x) \notin \{-1, 0\}$ for  all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Since $m$ is continuous, either $m(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$ or $m(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$.

- **Case 1.** Assume that $m(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$. This means that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$. Since $f$ is surjective, this implies that $f(x) < 0$ for some $x < 0$, then by the same argument, we find that $m(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

  Now notice that $m$ solves the following functional equation

  $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \ : \quad m(x+f(x)) = \phi(m(x)), \qquad \phi(a) = \frac{2}{1+a}. \tag{*} $$

  By the surjectivity and continuity of $f$, we easily check that $\{x+f(x):x \neq 0\} = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. So by $\text{(*)}$, we know that $\mathsf{Ran}(m) := \{ m(x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\} \}$ satisfies $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq \mathsf{Ran}(\phi\circ m)$.

  Now, if $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (a, b)$ for some $a, b \in [0, \infty]$, then $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (\phi(b), \phi(a))$ holds as well. Then starting from $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (0, \infty)$ and iterating the previous observation, we have

  $$\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (\phi^{\circ(2n)}(0), \phi^{\circ(2n)}(\infty))$$

  and by letting $n\to\infty$ shows that $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq \{1\}$. Therefore $f(x) = x$.
- **Case 2.** Assume that $m(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$. The proof in this case will be quite similar as in the previous case, so we will skip some details.

  Again, we easily find that $m(x) < 0$ for all $x < 0$ as well. Now rewriting $\text{(*)}$ as

  $$ m(x) = \psi(m(x+f(x))), \qquad \psi(a) = \frac{2}{a} - 1 $$

  we find that $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq \mathsf{Ran}(\psi \circ m)$. Starting from $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (-\infty, 0)$ and iterating this relation, we easily find that

  $$ \mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq (\psi^{\circ(2n)}(-\infty), \psi^{\circ(2n)}(-1)) $$

  Letting $n\to\infty$ shows that $\mathsf{Ran}(m) \subseteq \{-2\}$, from which it follows that $f(x) = -2x$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an odd example of your functional equation, which is additive (that is, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$) but not of the form $f(x)=kx$.

Let $B$ be a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis) of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$; that is, we will regard $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. It is known that we can decompose $B=B_0\cup B_1$ into disjoint linearly independent sets with *same cardinailty*. That is, we can find an index set $I$ such that
$$B_0 = \{a_i :i\in I\}\text{ and } B_1 =\{c_i : i\in I\}.$$

We will define $f$ over whole $\mathbb{R}$ via defining it over a basis. Take 
$$f(a_i) = -\frac{1}{2}a_i+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}c_i \quad\text{  and   }\quad f(c_i) = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}a_i-\frac{1}{2}c_i.$$ We can see that $f(f(b))+f(b) = 2b$ for all $b\in B$, hence $f(f(x))+f(x)=2x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $f(x) = kx$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$, then $k$ must be 0 or 2. Moreover, $(k-1)a_i-c_i=0$ for any $i$. However it is not possible as $\{a_i,c_i\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: It would be interesting if we can find other solution whose existence does not rely on the axiom of choice.

Comment: For problems like this, it is often the case that there are the simple, nice, linear solutions, and then there are the solutions depending on the axiom of choice. The standard example is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. That being said, I would also like to see one, if possible.